# Windows Phone Push Notifications without a web service

Tags: windows-phone-8, notifications, cloud, mpns

I'm planning to develop windows phone app which can send my PC clipboard to the phone. I want to use push notifications for this. I found this paragraph on the msdn windows phone documentation library

> After your Windows Phone client app has registered for notifications, you can send notifications to the app. Typically, this is done with a web service that keeps a collection of URIs to send notifications to, but **it also can be done with any app that can send messages to the Microsoft Push Notification Service.**

This seems to imply that I *don't* need to set up a web service. Is there some way I can send push notifications directly from my app to MPNS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your desktop app can communicate directly with MPNS.

Use the same code as for the web service.